# Setting the window's position in ICommands not working

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have a simple WPF Application that has a menu on top. I am trying to bind a shortcut to one of the menu items, but I cannot figure this out. Please mind that I am doing this as a hobby and quite new to this.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+R" Command="{Binding RepositionWindowCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<MenuItem Header="_Options">
    <MenuItem x:Name="Menu_RepositionWindow" Header="_Reposition Window" Command="{Binding RepositionWindowCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+R" />
</MenuItem>
```

MainMenu.cs

```
namespace WPF_Practice
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new PracticeDataContext();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RepositionWindow();
        }

        public void RepositionWindow()
        {
            Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - Width;
            Top = 0;
        }
    }

    public class PracticeDataContext
    {
        public ICommand RepositionWindowCommand { get; } = new RepositionWindowCommand();
    }

    public class RepositionWindowCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var RepositionWindowClass = new MainWindow();
            RepositionWindowClass.RepositionWindow();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    }
}
```

The goal here is to move the main window to top right corner whenever I click the menu item, or use the shortcut key of Ctrl+R. I also tried to put Top, Left, and Width in ICommand just in case like below to this if it solves the problem.

```
    public class RepositionWindowCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - Width;
            Top = 0;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    }
```

It does not recognize Left, Top, and Width when they are in ICommand. It says "The name does not exist in current context."

What am I missing here? How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Left is not a property of RepositionWindowCommand. It is a property of Window. Your command logic should be in some other class that can access the Window. You generally don't  derive from ICommand. See RelayCommand or DelegateCommand which are common implementations of ICommand that allow you to specify methods to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, you don't need to create `RepositionWindowClass` inside `RepositionWindowCommand`. To access a `Window` instance inside command you should pass it as parameter to command using `CommandParameter` binding. You also should properly implement `CanExecuteChanged` event

```cs
    public class RepositionWindowCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is Window window)
            {
                 window.Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - window.Width;
                 window.Top = 0;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
```

Xaml usage

```
<MenuItem x:Name="Menu_RepositionWindow" Header="_Reposition Window" Command="{Binding RepositionWindowCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+R" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: This solved the problem I had, but what could I do if I wanted to create `RepositionWindowClass` inside `RepositionWindowCommand`? I want to add more commands that will be definitely longer than just couple lines of codes that could be called from different classes.

Comment: You shouldn't do that, it's violation of MVVM and command pattern:) You can pass the window instance to command as parameter. You can also incapsulate your logic into separate classes and reuse. Main window instance is always available through `Application.Current.MainWindow` property, there is no need to create one more